# Is there an API to write functional tests for smart card access?

Tags: java, functional-testing, smartcard-reader

Is there a Java based API to simulate smart card access and thereby write functional tests for a functionality that depends on data read from smart card? We use contact based readers in this case so simulation is needed if we want to write functional tests. I have heard about jCardSim but not sure if it is applicable or how to use it (examples)?

Comment: May I know why this question was down voted? I definitely need to find an API to write functional test code for smart card access and the category for down vote seems to be of "off-topic". I can't understand how it appears to be off topic, when my question looks at least to me to be programming related?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a terminal for the `javax.smartcardio` library. That terminal doesn't have to be an actual terminal, it can also be a virtual one. This is also how jCardSim works, last time I looked anyway.

Of course you don't need all that if you just have to test the "data read from the smart card". Data can be stored on disk and the encoding can be tested separately.